# Crear componentes dinamicos con React.CreateElement con react.js

Tags: reactjs, map

Buen dia.

```
{
    ['Dashboard', 'Code', 'ViewModule', 'RecentActors', 'CloudQueue', 'SyncProblem', 'Apps', 'SupervisorAccount', 'Settings'].map((texto, index) => (

        <ListItem button key={texto}>
           <ListItemIcon>
           {
              React.createElement(texto, {className : texto}, texto)
           }
         </ListItemIcon>
         <ListItemText primary={texto} />
       </ListItem>
    ))
}
```

[image: Dom]

Como se puede ver en el código e imagen anterior trato de crear un componente en base al arreglo que estoy iterando pero no se crea el componente del mismo tipo si no que en a nivel de html se mira que crea una etiqueta con el mismo nombre pero con minúsculas.

[image: Detalle del código generado en html]

Solo por cuestion de pruebas si en vez de poner la variable texto al crear el elemento pongo el nombre de un componente importado como podría ser un icono de material UI por ejemplo ViewModule crea todos los componentes de ese tipo.

[image: prueba]

Aqui la idea final es poder construir un menu dinámico en base a iteración con un map creando los componentes que se reciban.

Saludos.

Comment: tiempo atras encontre esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120269/cannot-create-an-element-in-react-component-dynamically

puede que te funcione, lo negativo es que tienes que crear cada componente que tienes en tu arreglo

Comment: Gracias, revisare el tema y en cuanto tenga respuesta clara tratare de comentar mi respuesta para que esten enterados.